# Compile postfix with EAI support

Tags: email, postfix

I am using Centos 5.6 , trying to compile  postfix-3.1.3 with EAI support. I am following [this guide](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html) and executing

```
yum install libicu-devel "dependencies"
make makefiles
make install
```

After installation I got the following warning:

> **smtputf8_enable is true, but EAI support is not compiled in**

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix needs to be recompiled after the installation of libicu-devel. When this library is not available during compile time, postfix will not link against it.